# ASP.NET MVC: push value (int) to anouther page that will automatically select an item from a drop downbox using that value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a dropdown on a `Create` page, and I would like it to select one of the options by passing a value from a previous page.

I have a url `/Create/?1`

That passes the id value to the controller of a page

```
public IActionResult Create(int? id)
```

My code then creates a view model and then returns to the `Create` page.

```
// GET-Create        
public IActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    LocationVM locationVM = new LocationVM()
               {
                   Location = new Location(),
                   TypeDropDown = _db.LocationTypes.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = i.Name,
                       Value = i.Id.ToString()
                   })                
               };

    return View(locationVM);
}

// POST-Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(LocationVM obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //obj.ExpenseTypeId = 1;
        _db.Locations.Add(obj.Location);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(obj);
}
```

The location page consists of 4 fields

```
RecordId, Location (drop down),  Name (String),  Notes (String)
```

Any help in pushing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So... what is your question? What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a `<a href="/test/index/2">direct to hello</a>` in a view so that when we click this link, we would redirect to our target controller action. Here I need to say, the default template for MVC is `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` so if you used `/Create/?1` and `public IActionResult Create(int? id)`, the id in controller would always be null.

Here's my controller and view:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "localtion1", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "localtion2", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "localtion3", Value = "3" }
        };
        int targetId = (int)(id == null ? 0 : id);
        LocationVM vm = new LocationVM
        {
            Notes = "notes",
            RecordId = 1,
            LocationList = items,
            SelectedLocaltionId = targetId,
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
}

public class LocationVM
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> LocationList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedLocaltionId { get; set; }
}

public class Location 
{
    public int localtionId { get; set; }
    public string localtionName { get; set; }
}

@model WebAppMvc.Controllers.LocationVM;

<form asp-controller="Hello" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SelectedLocaltionId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select id="selectCountry" class="form-control" asp-for="SelectedLocaltionId"
                asp-items="Model.LocationList">
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="SelectedLocaltionId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And my test result.

[image]

By the way, if you are using html helper, then you might try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedLocaltionId, Model.testList)
```

Comment: Thank you so very very much, it was really annoying me.  Today I coded a Table Cell styler from SQL, and managed to get 90 lines of code in to 9 and thought I was having a good day, and then I saw your replay and now I'm having the best day xxx

Comment: that's great to hear that : )